# Improving with Array instead of IF

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to use an Array instead of IF, I think that is more efficient but I don't how exactly do it sorry, I am new in C#, can someone just give me an good example please? I have a lot of Cliente.Contains and I think "If" is not the correct way, this is the code:

```
if (Cliente.Contains("0003919026"))
{
nombreCliente = "TELMOV";
}
if (Cliente.Contains("0002402248"))
{
nombreCliente = "Workplay S.A. DE C.V.";
}
if (Cliente.Contains("0009206605"))
{
nombreCliente = "SISTEMAS Y SERVICIOS DE (SYSCOM)";
}

CadenaRes = "Se proceso el archivo el dia " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n" + "El archivo con nombre: " + nombreCliente;

Console.WriteLine("Carga Satisfactoria: {0} ", transfer.FileName);
```

Comment: try with `Dictionary<K,V>`

Comment: Typo? You've put `if (Cliente.Contains("0009206605"))` fragment twice

Comment: If you have a lot of things to select from, you might want to consider storing that data in a file so that it can be changed without re-compiling the program.

Comment: Do you *require* "Contains" or could you just test for equality? In other words, that Cliente, does is contain *only* that number (then use equality) , or more text around it (then you need Contains) ?

Comment: What do you want to happen if `Cliente` contains both `0003919026` and `0002402248`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve your task using Dictionary like following:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("0003919026", "TELMOV");
dic.Add("0002402248", "Workplay S.A. DE C.V.");
dic.Add("0009206605", "SISTEMAS Y SERVICIOS DE (SYSCOM)");
dic.Add("0009206605", "Se proceso el archivo el dia" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n" + "El archivo con nombre: " + nombreCliente);

nombreCliente = dic.FirstOrDefault(x => Cliente.contains(x));
```

You can also use list of a class containing your key and value. Then use linq to get your required value.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can organize substitution pairs (what to find and what to show) into a collection, say an array and implement something like this:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string nombreCliente = ...

(string find, string show)[] subs = new[] {
  ("0009206605", "SISTEMAS Y SERVICIOS DE (SYSCOM)"),
  ("0002402248", "Workplay S.A. DE C.V."),
  //TODO: Add more pairs here
};

// Reverse: according to the code in the question, the later pair should prevail; 
// if it's not possible we can drop .Reverse()
foreach (var pair in subs.Reverse())
  if (Cliente.Contains(pair.find)) {
    nombreCliente = pair.show;

    break;
  }

CadenaRes = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
  $"Se proceso el archivo el dia {DateTime.Now}",
  $"El archivo con nombre: {nombreCliente}",
);

Console.WriteLine($"Carga Satisfactoria: {transfer.FileName}");
```

But I doubt in underlying logic: we are looking for just a fragment, and the assign `nombreCliente`;
what if `Cliente` is *combined*, say `0009206605 and (0002402248)`?